# Show last uploaded image HTML-PHP-JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, ftp

I do have to show the last image uploaded to an FTP server on a website page.
Since the client I use to upload files to the FTP tries to connect to a localhost (127.0.0.1) I don't know why, I decided to use the FTP integrated system in the DLink IP webcam. The problem is that this system upload the photos normally, but in different folders for date and time (e.g.: folder: `/20161211` (date) subfolder: `/11` (time)).

I have already tried to upload to the ftp using the webcam snapshot setup and also I tried to upload the output image of a "video client" to the FTP but this one doesn't work since it tries to connect to localhost instead of the webcam ip (`192.168.1.66`) also if was set up.

So how can I show on the website the last uploaded image?

Comment: Ciao Simone, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have already tried to upload to the ftp using the webcam snapshot setup and also I tried to upload the output image of a "video client" to the FTP but this one doen not work since it tries to connect to localhost instead of the webcam ip (192.168.1.66) also if was set up.